# Date format from sheets to gmail using gscript

Tags: google-apps-script

My date value is not formatting correctly when pulling date from Sheets into a Gmail using Gscript

I've tried formatting the date within Sheets using all possible ways (date, automatic, plain text).

```
var body = "Dear " + row[1] +
```

I'm just pulling the date in using a `+ row [x]` function, and I have the date within Sheets in a cell. It always pulls up as:

> Mon Jun 24 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST).

I just want to return the month, date and year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: getDisplayValues(). Once formatted appropriately in Sheets, this will convert it as it is seen in Sheets.